# Do we need SSL certificate on client side to consume https web service API

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ssl, https

My code is in .net 4.5

Web service API is in https

Do we any need SSL certificate on client side code to consume https web service API?

My web.config as below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://example.com/webservice.asmx"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
        contract="mynamespace.MyServicesSoap" name="MyServicesSoap" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyServicesSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: A client certificate in SSL is optional. It is up to the server to decide if it requires the client to provide a certificate or not.

Comment: Is there any way to know whether server requires SSL certificate? In my case, my service provider has provided test wsdl over http which I can access in visual studio but as per them they have provided live link over https which I am not able to access. I am not able to consume https API, any clues?